# How do I return a dynamically allocated array to main?

Tags: c, function, return, malloc, dynamic-arrays

I suspect that I have a problem in saving the values that I need to save to the dynamically allocated array, as well as in returning the said dynamically allocated array.

Apparently this is a famous interview question I'm trying to solve on LeetCode. The function receives an array, its size, a target, and a pointer (It is my understanding that I have to allocate a dynamic array to this pointer). I have to check if there are two numbers in the array whose sum is equal to the target, if that's the case then I have to save their indices in a dynamically allocated array (It is my understanding that its size=2), and then I have to return this array.

I have tried looking at the provided solution on LeetCode, I understand it, but it does not help me understand what is the problem with my solution.

I tried looking at similar question here on stackoverflow, but I also couldn't find something that would help me understand my what I'm doing wrong and how to correct it.

Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    int i,j;

    //Allocating a dynamic memory to the received pointer, i.e.
    //setting a dynamic array.
    returnSize=malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    if(!returnSize){
        printf("Memory allocation error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Searching for two numbers in 'nums' whose sum is equal to 'target',
    //if found, save their indices to the dynamically allocated array
    //and return it, if not, return the array with [-1,-1].
    for(i=0;i<numsSize;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<numsSize;j++){
            if(nums[i]+nums[j]==target){
                returnSize[0]=i;
                returnSize[1]=j;
                return returnSize;
            }
        }
    }

    returnSize[0]=-1;
    returnSize[1]=-1;
    return returnSize;
}
```

The output of nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], and target = 9,

is a dynamically allocated array with the values [0, 1].

Comment: No, `returnSize` will tell the caller how many values are in the array you return. So in this case 2. It’s a pointer because otherwise you couldn’t assign a value to the caller’s variable.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I don't think so. Here's how the question reads at LeetCode:

**_"Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1]."_**

And also there's this note:

**_"Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free()."_**

So, I'm sure that what must be returned a dynamic array.

Comment: Yes, what must be *returned* is a pointer to an array. But `returnSize` is not a return value, it contains the size.

Comment: I'm not sure why you even need `returnSize`.  It sounds like you are always going to return a 2-element array, as the return value, so why not eliminate the function argument and just make it a local variable (preferably with a different name)?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen So, 'returnSize' is the size of the malloced array that must be returned? which should always be equal to 2? because **"You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution"**, so the size is always 2 because the solution will always have 2 indices. Correct?

Comment: @TomKarzes I know, it makes sense, but the function declaration was already assigned by LeetCode, not by me, that's why I understood that returnSize should be a pointer to which you assign a dynamic array.

Comment: It may be a matter of them mechanically porting it to C.  If it really is meant to be the size, again create a new, local variable for the return array, and for `returnSize` just do `*returnSize = 2;` right before returning the array, `return myArray;`  So the return value is the array you create, and `*returnSize` is updated to give the length of the returned array.

Comment: @TomKarzes Good news mate, it works now following your suggestion. Thank you for your time and have a nice day, this question may rip now :)

Comment: Thank you for everyone who has taken the time to answer my question :)

Comment: "*//Searching for two numbers in 'nums' whose sum is equal to 'target' ...*" not just for *two* numbers. It's part of the game that *you* need to find out how many number inside `nums` add up to `target`. The result is greater equal one and less equal `target`. This number needs to be written to `*returnSize`. An array of exactly this value has to be allocated and filled with the incidences to `nums` indicating the elements of `nums` needed to sum up to `target`. This array is returned by the function.